# why am I getting this each_key method error for ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash

Here is my method

```
def dict(hash = {})
  hash.each_key do |key|
    if(hash[key] == nil)
      p nil
    else
      p hash[key]
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to accept these parameters as arguments
dict('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
or
dict('fish)
but I keep getting this error

```
practice:36:in `dict': undefined method `each_key' for "fish":String (NoMethodError)                                                                                                          
        from practice:45:in `<main>'
```

I'm relatively new so I dont understand how I'm using this wrong please help

Comment: exception is telling exactly what happened.. you method `#dict` got  a _string_ object instead of _hash_ object.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the method with just `dict('fish')` the `hash` parameter is being set to the string `'fish'`. The Ruby string class does not have a method called `each_key`, so you are getting a no method error.

Ruby string API:
http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html

Since you'll need to accept both a string and a hash argument, you'll have to check the argument class in your method.

```
def dict(word)
  case word
  when String
    # do what should be done for 'fish'
  when Hash
    # do what should be done for 'fish' => 'aquatic animal'
  end
end
```

See [this article](http://batsov.com/articles/2012/10/14/ruby-tip-number-3-matching-on-an-objects-class-in-a-case-expression/) for an explanation of how class matching in case statements works.

Comment: what do I have to do to get the compiler to understand that I want it to be the key to a hash?

Comment: You would need to provide a key value pair, as you have done with your first example call `dict('fish' => 'aquatic animal')`. If you want a blank value you could pass in nil: `dict('fish' => nil)`

Comment: I can't it is part of the specs https://github.com/appacademy/test-first-ruby/blob/master/spec/11_dictionary_spec.rb

Comment: Ahh I see. From those specs, it looks like your method needs to expect either a string or a hash as the parameter. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I found a way to do this by using variable arguments dict(*arg) allows any number of arguments you just got to unpack them from arg